# Select max value for a VARCHAR column - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

My table for message inbox concept email is a primary in the table. I want to get the last message which is sent by particular email.

**tbl_msg:**

```
id
email
msg
```

Example Data:

```
Id  email            msg
1   xyz@gmail.com    This is test    
2   abc@gmail.com    All is well
3   xyz@gmail.com    This is test2
```

I want to get the last appearance of each email and msg

```
Id  email            msg

2   abc@gmail.com    All is well
3   xyz@gmail.com    This is test2
```

What I tried:

```
SELECT cnote.`id`,cnote.`email`,cnote.`msg` FROM `tbl_msg` cnote inner join (select distinct email,id from client_com group by email) as note
on cnote.id=note.id
```

Guide me if I wrong

Comment: you may be overthinking this. Why not just last_insert_id?

Comment: true...just fetch last inserted record

Comment: for getting last_inserted_id for every email?

Comment: I misunderstood the question then.

Answer (score 1):

To get the latest messsage *for each* email address in the table you do not need a `JOIN`, you just need to `ORDER` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT `id`, `email`, `msg`
FROM `tbl_msg`
GROUP BY `email`
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by email LIMIT 0, 30' at line 2

Comment: I do not have a `LIMIT` clause in my query @SarathJasrin. Are you using this with additional code?

Comment: select * from (SELECT * FROM `tbl_msg` order by id desc) as n
 group by email

Comment: I am not using a sub-select either.

Comment: I'm not using any additional query which is default by phpmyadmin.thanks

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to say here @SarathJasrin

Comment: While using sub query the concept is working fine other it's giving error

Comment: I made an edit to my query @SarathJasrin to change the order of the GROUP and ORDER statements.

Answer (score 1):

Use This query:

```
SELECT m1.* FROM tbl_msgs m1 LEFT JOIN tbl_msgs m2  ON (m1.email = m2.email AND m1.id < m2.id) WHERE m2.id IS NULL;
```

This will join with the same table and with condition `m1.id < m2.id` , will get the latest one.

Another option is using subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_msgs WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl_msgs GROUP BY email);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT id, email, msg FROM you_table 
GROUP BY email
ORDER BY id DESC
```

With this one you will have only 1 row per email, and you'll have the last because is ordered by id DESC.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a `PDO` connection (The way I know to do it, not sure if there is a MySQLi way)

```
$theLastIdGiven = $handlerDbConnection->lastInsertId();
```

Or if you want to run it through a query, and get the last result, just add `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1` and that will order the data by id in a descending form then get the first bit of data :)

Hope this helped you!

Comment: Connection has nothing to do with the query

Comment: I know that. I mean the function names for getting the last ID are different, I don't know the get last id function name for MySQLi, like PSM has a get last connection function of `glid`, PDO's one is `lastInsertId()` :) @JayBlanchard

Comment: But that will only get you one result and the OP needs the last message for *all* of the emails in the table.

Comment: You can do that. Just use the ID gotten from the `$handler->lastInsertId()` if there was something inserted last and then you can get from that. Other than that if that isn't what he wants, then he can use my second method. Don't see what the problem is

Comment: Oh, there's no problem. Just a best practice: always let the tool designed to do the heavy lifting do it.

Comment: Of course :) @JayBlanchard And sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ID, email, Msg FROM tbl_msg WHERE ID IN (
(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tbl_msg GROUP BY email))